# Arduino: Extract word from string and pass it to a float variable

Tags: c++, arduino

How do I extract the weight value from the string below?

> [GET **/weight/250/** HTTP/1.1 Host: 192.168.1.2:8080 Connection: Keep-Alive]

How do I need it to stay:

```
float weight = 250
```

Comment: You can't dynamically name variables in C++.

Comment: This is similar question, to [the one you already asked](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44163924/find-word-within-a-string) and still without any effort shown, that you tried anything yourself.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In Arduino you can use the [substring](https://www.arduino.cc/en/Tutorial/StringSubstring) function followed by a [toFloat](https://www.arduino.cc/en/Reference/StringToFloat) function:

```
void setup() {
  // put your setup code here, to run once:
}

void loop() {
  String stringOne = "[GET /weight/250/ HTTP/1.1 Host: 192.168.1.2:8080 Connection: Keep-Alive]";
  String stringTwo = stringOne.substring(13, 16);
  float weight = stringTwo.toFloat();

  // do nothing while true:
  while (true);
}
```